# why data is not passing in route correctly in angular13?

Tags: angular, routes

I have an `angular13` application in which i am passing data from one `component` to another via `route data`. Inside of my `componentA` i have this function

```
navigateTo(data: any){
  this._router.navigateByUrl(url, { state: data});  // {id: 1, age: 3} //
}
```

And in my `componentB` i am accessing the data in this way

```
  constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private location: Location
  ) {
       if (this.router.url.includes('edit')) {
          this.isEdit = true;
          console.log(this.location.getState());
       }
  }
```

But it's always printing this in `console` in `componentB`.

```
{navigationId:  6 //(random id each time)}
```

Why data is not passing correctly?

Comment: Hi! How exactly do you get the value of 'navigationId' in componentB? You didn't show it.

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero i mentioned in my post that how it is printing on console in `componentB`. I updated my post please see that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question, because I guess that "this.location.getState()" is not the right method to get your data (at least, in the "Angular way").

Try this:

```
console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id)
```

More info [HERE](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state)

Comment: I also have tried this but this always prints undefined

Comment: ok, but... now I see that you try to get the value in the constructor.Could you try both ways to get the id, but in the 'ngOnInit()' method instead?